# Copy command issue in Macbook Air

Tags: shell

I had faced this issue earlier on the Mac of one of my friends and dismissed it as being something wrong with his Mac, but since I faced it today, it got me a bit worried.

To replicate the issue do the following in a terminal

```
mkdir -p cp_test/source_folder
echo "This is the file inside" >cp_test/source_folder/trial.txt
echo "This is the file outside" >cp_test/Trial.txt
cd cp_test/
diff Trial.txt source_folder/trial.txt
cp source_folder/trial.txt .
diff Trial.txt source_folder/trial.txt
```

So basically what happens in my case is that the first time I do a diff, the difference is correctly shown. But the second time there is no difference.

What I gather is that the 'cp' command is copying the file trial.txt to the current directory, and renaming it to Trial.txt (Check the case for the filenames)

I am considering this as a bug, because I don't see this happening on my digital ocean server (Ubuntu 14.04). Not really sure if it is a bug or it is another case of "Apple just does things differently".

Answer (score 1):

This behavior depends on the file system, which may be "case preserving" but "case insensitive" at the same time.

Comment: You might just be right.
I tried running
mkdir trial, and then mkdir Trial, and it threw an error. But ls seems to be case sensetive. Any idea how i can make it so that this does not cause an issue to me?

Comment: Do you mean you want to convert the file system to case sensitive? AFAIK, HFS+ has a case sensitive flavor but on an your operating system you may break a lot of old programs by converting the whole system. A safe choice is to to create and mount a case sensitive partition for work which depends on it.